# Creating menulet osx app with custom view in swift

Tags: objective-c, macos, swift, menubar

Has anyone been able to make menulet osx app with custom view. There is really nice Objective-C example here: https://github.com/djromero/PopoverMenulet but no idea how to convert into Swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 10.10 NSStatusBar.setView has been deprecated and I guess this is the main reason this can not be implemented in Swift
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSStatusItem_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000248-SW3

see section: Managing a Custom View

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert into swift, you should be able to include it into the bridging header and use it as is. See [How to call Objective-C code from Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift)

Comment: I like the idea but you still have to maintain some Objective-C like the view controllers. I will try it out, thanks!